# how can i make a button to reroll the dice with the same form data using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm using Flask for my app and now i'm learning some of Javascript.
I'm doing a dice app in which you submit some values (number of dice, etc) and then roll the dice. I want to reroll the same dice and resubmit the same values with a button.
I have been said that I can do this with jquery and ajax, but I don't find the right method. Should I reload only the roll, and let the rest without changes? Should I reload the roll and recall the submit data as JSON? Should I copy the browser process of reload and confirm resubmit data?
This is the code of the views:

```py
@app.route('/juego', methods=['GET'])
def juego():
    form = CumuloForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('resjuego'))
    return render_template('juego.html', title='A ver!', form=form)

@app.route('/resjuego', methods=['GET','POST'])
def resjuego():
    form = CumuloForm()
    signo=request.form.get('signo')
    pool=request.form.get('pool')
    magnitud=request.form.get('magnitud')
    x = int(pool)
    m = int(magnitud)
    i=0
    roll=Dado.signar(x)
    res=roll
    y=rnd.randint(1,6)
    entropia=Dado.signar(y)
    thislist=[]
    thislist2=[]
    for i in range(x):
        thislist.append(Aspecto.aspectario(signo, res[0+i]))
        zumbi = thislist
    for i in range(y):
        thislist2.append(Aspecto.aspectario(signo, entropia[0+i]))
        zumbi2 = thislist2
    totalasp=zumbi+zumbi2
    conj = 2*(zumbi.count("conjunción"))
    semsex = 0*(zumbi.count("semisextil"))
    sext = 1*(zumbi.count("sextil"))
    cuad = -1*(zumbi.count("cuadratura"))
    trig = 1*(zumbi.count("trígono"))
    quinc = 0*(zumbi.count("quincuncio"))
    opos = -2*(zumbi.count("oposición"))

    conj2 = 2*(zumbi2.count("conjunción"))
    semsex2 = 0*(zumbi2.count("semisextil"))
    sext2 = 1*(zumbi2.count("sextil"))
    cuad2 = -1*(zumbi2.count("cuadratura"))
    trig2 = 1*(zumbi2.count("trígono"))
    quinc2 = 0*(zumbi2.count("quincuncio"))
    opos2 = -2*(zumbi2.count("oposición"))

    éxitos = conj + semsex + sext + cuad + trig + quinc + opos
    éxitosent= conj2 + semsex2 + sext2 + cuad2 + trig2 + quinc2 + opos2
    if éxitos + m <=0:
        rest="fallo"
    if éxitos >=0:
        rest="éxito"
    if éxitos <=0 and éxitos + m >=0:
        rest="adverso"
    des_exitos = descriptorc(rest)

    T1 = struli(zumbi)
    T2 = struli(zumbi2)
    res=struli(res)
    entropia=struli(entropia)
    

    return render_template('resjuego.html', title='Caosmos', lanzarcum=res, signo = signo, entropia=entropia, aspecto=T1, aspecto2=T2, éxitos=éxitos, éxitosent = éxitosent, des_exitos=des_exitos)
```

update: this is the back of the query

```py
@app.route('/back_retirada')
def back_retirada():
    signo = request.form.get('signo')
    pool =  request.form.get('pool')
    magnitud = request.form.get('magnitud')
    return jsonify(signo=signo, pool=pool, magnitud=magnitud)
```

this is the html (where i'm trying to apply Ajax):

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}
{% block app_content %}
<head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type=text/javascript>
            $ function() {
                $('#re_tirada').on('click', 
                $.getJSON('/back_retirada', {signo: signo, magnitud:magnitud, pool: pool}, function(data) {$("#result").text(data);
                }
                )
            }

                
        </script>
    </head>

        <h1>✹     Tu ascendente y magnitud    ✹</h1>
        <p class='formula'> {{signo}} </p>
        <div>
            <h1>✹ Tu cúmulo astral ✹</h1>
            <p class='formula' href=# id=result> {{lanzarcum}} <p>  
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>✹ Entropía ✹</h1>
            <p class='formula'> {{entropia}} <p>   
        </div>
        <div>
        <h1>✹ Cálculo de éxitos✹</h1>

        <p class = 'instrucciones'>Cúmulo: {{aspecto}} ✹ puntaje: {{éxitos}}<p>
        <p class = 'instrucciones'>Entropía: {{aspecto2}} ✹ puntaje: {{éxitosent}}<p>
        <p class = 'instrucciones'>
            {{des_exitos}} <p>
        <br>
        </div>

<div class='text-center'>
    <form>
        <span href=# id=re_tirada><button type="submit" value="submit">¡Lanza otra vez!</button> </span>
    </form>
</div>
<br>
<div class='text-center'>
    <form action= " {{(url_for('juego'))}}" method="get">
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Vuelve atrás</button>
    </form>
</div>
<br>
<div class='text-center'>
    <form action= " {{(url_for('index'))}}" method="get">
    <button class="home" type="submit" value="submit"> Al inicio...</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

and this is my app: https://astrodados.herokuapp.com/juego

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reload the page. Have a button to roll the dice and when user clicks on the button, you use Ajax to submit it to your backend (flask application).

If you use Ajax, then you don't have to reload the page and essentially the page stays as is (also means you don't lose user data). User can then click the button again if they wish to roll the dice a second time and again you use Ajax to submit the contents.

After this second roll, you can then disable the button (if you only want the user to be able to roll the button twice) or you can then reload the page

Updating the answer based on comments added by OP

1. jquery.bind has been deprecated. You should use jquery.on("click"). See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/bind/)
2. You are calling [Jquery.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) which is for returning JSON data but you are returning an html page via render_template. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54603391/15211203) for a structure of an Ajax call

Comment: Thank you. That's what i've been trying to do. I have edited the question to add the html where i'm trying to use Ajax.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comments

Comment: Thank you very much. I have done some changes to my code: added a different view as a background of the process i want to do, and I ask it for the json. But it doesn't work. The error is that data is not being received, so the roll can't be done.

Comment: If you have made changes to your code, please update your post with the updated code. Your post still shows the old code

Comment: sorry, I had put the new view in the same block of code. Now I put it in an independent block. I'm calling that view (/back_retirada) from the script in /resjuego.html.